# button creates bad effects on small buttons on click

Tags: css, button, position

I have a problem in my project. I have some buttons side by side. 1st one is big, 2nd one is medium and 3rd one small button. 3 of the buttons have almost same css property except padding and color. When the 1st one gets clicked other Buttons change their position. when 2nd and 3rd one is clicked they don't get down. I know this happening for holder padding and 1st one,s height. I want the effect like 1st button. 2nd and 3rd one just remove border and they don't come down like 1st one. Is there is any solution for fix this?

```
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
.super-holder {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f06060;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a:active, a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}
.btn1 {
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 26px;
    background-color: #9C27B0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn1:active {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: #FFF;

}
.btn2 {
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #79B039;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn2:active {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: #FFF;

}
.btn3 {
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn3:active {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

[demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/fxcecw9a/)

Comment: do you want the same effect for btn2 and btn3 as in btn 1 or something else.?

Comment: I just want to change css bg color by js in dom and size.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle Demo below.

Comment: yes I checked. By the way thanks for your great support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css

```
.super-holder div{
    float:left;
    height:80px;
    width:120px;
}
.clear{clear:both}
```

And wrap your buttons in a `div`

```
<div class="super-holder">
    <div><a class="btn1">Button</a></div>
    <div><a class="btn2">Button</a></div>
    <div><a class="btn3">Button</a></div>
    <p class='clear'></p>
</div>
```

Here is the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp10kkxj/)**

Comment: Thanks [CodeRomeos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5237897/coderomeos) for understand my problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is your `margin-bottom: 4px` on btn1:active. If you do this the button will move which I don't think you want.

As far as the borders go you might be better served with something like a drop-shadow, or even better a gradient that you could change on active. The problem is that your border is being added to the height of your button instead of being "inside" the bounds of your button. Instead, use something like this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to generate a gradient that can change when the element becomes active. That way the color change will happen within the element.

Comment: sorry [Silvertail](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5248801/silvertail) I can't explained my css in right way. Please see the question 2nd time. I corrected my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change .button1: active styling to this:

```
.btn1:active {
     position: relative;
     border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
     margin-bottom: 4px;  /* <--- THIS */
     color: #FFF;    
 }
```

Comment: sorry [Marin Nedea](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4891622/marin-nedea) I can't explained my css in right way. Please see the question 2nd time. I corrected my explanation.

Comment: no problem @ShohidulAlam . Indeed, I didn't correctly understood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your  support.